# Fast way to find the night-mode of a picture in canvas?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

What would be a computationally inexpensive way of finding the night-mode of an image in `canvas`?

Doesn't have to superb just fast way to turn an image from visiually day to night.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Can you please explain in further detail what you mean by "night mode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to experiment with different exact levels and values, but I'd desaturate the color, then dim the image, more strongly on the R and G components than the B component so that the resulting image was slightly blue-tinted.

Do you know how to draw an image into a `canvas`, grab the pixels, loop through the pixels to manipulate them, then draw them back?

Comment: I was thinking more of making the dimming layer and just layering it on top of the picture which I think should be faster and yes I do know that. But it's interesting I thought it was an already solved problem in image processing with a defined algorithm but I guess not. Thanks.